# Yii2 ajax не работает. Редирект на страницу запроса

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

Вставляю просто ajax запрос. Но не важно GET, POST всё равно открывается страница на которую делается запрос. На другом сайта всё нормально. Явно дело в какой то настройки в конфиги. Может кто знает в чем причина?

```
$(favorite).click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var type = $(this).data('type');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/wishlist/add',
        data: "type=" + type + "&id=" + id,
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg != 'yes') {
                alert(msg);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Киньте скрин запроса с консоли, чтоб выдны были заголоки

Comment: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: Что находится в переменной `favorite`?

Comment: вы меня натолкнули на мысль и я нашел косяк. в config.php есть параметр on beforeRequest так вот в нем проблема, надо его поправить. Спасибо

Comment: Напиши решение в ответе. Возможно кому-то пригодится.